# NPM Installs Not Working as Intended

Tags: node.js, npm

Sometimes then I run npm commands in the ubuntu console, e.g.

npm install forever -g

I get such feedback from the console and it is unclear to me is it installed? Is this a list of dependencies? Is this an issue? How should I proceed fixing this?

```
forever@0.14.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever
    ├── colors@0.6.2
    ├── timespan@2.3.0
    ├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
    ├── nssocket@0.5.3 (eventemitter2@0.4.14, lazy@1.0.11)
    ├── cliff@0.1.10 (eyes@0.1.8, colors@1.0.3)
    ├── winston@0.8.3 (cycle@1.0.3, stack-trace@0.0.9, eyes@0.1.8, isstream@0.1.2, async@0.2.10, pkginfo@0.3.0)
    ├── nconf@0.6.9 (ini@1.3.4, async@0.2.9, optimist@0.6.0)
    ├── utile@0.2.1 (deep-equal@1.0.0, ncp@0.4.2, async@0.2.10, i@0.3.3, mkdirp@0.5.1, rimraf@2.4.0)
    ├── flatiron@0.4.3 (optimist@0.6.0, director@1.2.7, prompt@0.2.14, broadway@0.3.6)
    └── forever-monitor@1.5.2 (watch@0.13.0, minimatch@1.0.0, ps-tree@0.0.3, broadway@0.3.6)
```

Comment: Try to run your npm command as root user and it will give you the above output with addition of this line. `/usr/local/bin/forever -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever`, which is what you precisely want.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error message, everything installed just fine.

Output such as this shows you the other packages that were installed as dependencies for the package you have installed.

Comment: I can see /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever file in here, but when I run "forever" in the console it gives me forever: command not found

Comment: @funguy maybe you have problem with your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: try running `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever` in place of `forever`

Comment: This works /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever I guess the issue I am having is as Mohammad mentioned with the PATH than with npm itself.

Comment: run `npm link forever` then try again.
If this works it should 'link' to your global node_modules from your local node_modules